# Angular not updating view in $http.get().then()

Tags: angularjs

This is my template:

```
<p>{{$ctrl.status}}</p>
```

This is the component:

```
var phoneListModule = angular.module("phoneListModule");

phoneListModule.component("phoneList", {

    templateUrl: "phone-list/phone-list.template.html",

  controller: function PLController($http) {

    this.status = "testing";

    $http.get("http://localhost/data.json").then(function(response) {
        self.status = "again";
    });

  }

});
```

And this is the module:

```
var phoneListModule = angular.module("phoneListModule", []);
```

The problem is that, the view is compiled properly with the "testing" text, but it's never updated to "again" when the GET request completes.

A `console.log` confirms that it completed fine

```
console.log(self.status);
```

Inside of the `then()` method.

Why is the view not updating if the dataset has changed?

Comment: i think you should avoid using `this` or `self` because depending where you are ( like inside function or loop ) it means something different.

Try with `var vm = this ; vm.status = 'testing' ` and use `vm` after

Comment: Yeah, in the docs it's also suggested to put in var self = this;, and I overlooked that, it works now.

Answer (score 2):

`self` is not defined inside of the `then()` function, you need to define it at the start of the controller.

```
var phoneListModule = angular.module("phoneListModule");

phoneListModule.component("phoneList", {

    templateUrl: "phone-list/phone-list.template.html",

  controller: function PLController($http) {

    var self = this; <<<< THIS IS IMPORTANT

    this.status = "testing";

    $http.get("http://localhost/data.json").then(function(response) {
        self.status = "again";
    });

  }

});
```

Comment: Was it my suggestion that I deleted? Nice :) Thought I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

i think you should avoid using this or self because depending where you are ( like inside function or loop ) it means something different. Try with a variable pointing on `this` in the beggining of controller

```
phoneListModule.component("phoneList", {

    templateUrl: "phone-list/phone-list.template.html",

  controller: function PLController($http) {

    var vm = this ;
    vm.status = "testing";

    $http.get("http://localhost/data.json").then(function(response) {
        vm.status = "again";
    });

  }

});
```